# How to show download progress beneath status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to show a download progress bar beneath the status bar by either placing it on top of all other views (hiding whats under it) or by squeezing the rest. The bar will only be 9 px high. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application uses default navigation bar then you can't able to show progress bar beneath the status bar as navigation bar position is default at top of the view. You cant change that. But if you want to show progress bar with navigation bar then you need to customized the navigation bar.

And if your application doesn't have navigation bar then you can directly use progress bar on top of the view so that it will appear exact below to the status bar. Hope this will help you.